# angularjs validation directive with compiled template does not reflect 'max' attribute changes on dom

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I use following directiv to display custom validations:

```
 app.directive("validationMessages", ['$compile', ($compile: ng.ICompileService) => {
        return {
            require: "^form",
            replace: false,
            link: (scope, element, attrs, formCtrl) => {
                const fieldName = attrs["validationMessages"];
                const elementName = attrs["name"];
                const formName = formCtrl.$name;
                const elementFormKey = formName + "." + elementName;

                let html: string = `<div class="error" ng-show="${elementFormKey}.$invalid">`;

                for (const key in attrs) {
                    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(attrs, key)) {
                        const value = attrs[key];
                        switch (key) {
                           
                            case "ngMax":
                            case "max":
                                    html += `<small class="error ng-show="${
                                        elementFormKey}.$error.max">
                                        ${fieldName} must be less than or equal to ${value} abcd.
                                    </small>`;
                                
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                html += "</div>";

                let template = angular.element(html);
                let parser = $compile(template);
                let parsed = parser(scope);
                element.after(parsed);
            }
        };
    }]);
```

this code displays an error for an input like this

```
<input class="form-control"
                       ng-model="Vm.c0"
                       name="C0"
                       validation-messages="Constant C0"
                       max="{{Vm.maxValue}}"
                      />
```

Problem is, that changes to `VM.maxValue` are not being reflected by the template.
In fact the `link` function only runs once. Do I need to `watch` something?
Why is that?

UPDATE:

Finallay I think I now where the problem is - the `{{ }}` expression:
max="{{Vm.maxValue}}"

Is there another way to pass in `Vm.maxValue` ?

Comment: where you are setting maxValue ? can you try creating a demo to reproduce it.

Comment: well maxValue is a property on a model that can be changed dynamically. do you think this should work generally? maybe the problem is something else...

Comment: okay, can you try creating a demo? so that it can be analyzed. codewise it looks good.

Comment: i don't think i can strip down my project to a simple demo. would not how anyways

Comment: the changes to Vm.maxValue are made in a seperated ng-form that is bound to the same model. could this be the issue?

Comment: tests indicate that is is not the case..

Comment: is the code inside directive is getting executed when you change max value ?

Comment: no it is not. (debug mode)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221459/discussion-between-allabakash-and-ybother).

Answer (score 0):

In fact changes to attributes with expression bindings like `{{}}` are not being watched.
Adding a `scope.watch()` helps.